# Avoiding conflicts when two workflows push to the same branch in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

I have two workflows that are triggered at the same time and both push a commit to a branch.

While there's no risk of a merge conflict because both commits affect different files, the problem is that there's no merge at all. The two simultaneous commits result in diverging history on that branch, and only one of the commits is retained in the branch. The other is lost.

E.g. when branch `gh-pages` is at commit `A`, and two simultaneous workflows push commits `B` and `C` respectively:

[image: commit diagram]

What I'd like is for both commits to be retained on the branch. It doesn't matter what order they're in so long as they're there.

I can think of a couple of ways this might be possible:

1. The workflows need to be run in series rather than in parallel. I found a couple of Actions  that could be used for this, e.g. https://github.com/lewagon/wait-on-check-action, but these actions seem to *require* that the specified workfow be run or have finished running while the other action takes place. I can't guarantee this - either of my two actions could also be started individually.
2. There might be a Git-based way of getting around the issue - e.g. if I can find out the SHA of both commits, I can subsequently create a merge commit. But the two workflows, while started simultaneously, don't know about each others' existence... right?
3. Using `concurrency` and assigning both workflows to the same concurrency group such that only one can run at a time. But, the maximum queue length is 1 - there can only be one pending workflow at a time (any existing pending workflow is cancelled). This seems safe for 2 workflows, but does it scale to a hypothetical case of 3 or more simultaneous workflows (or even 3 workflows initiated within a few minutes of each other, depending on how long they take to complete)?

Given that the two workflows both create a commit on a given branch, and can be started simultaneously but could also be started individually, how can I make sure that both of those commits end up in the history of that branch?

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to run the jobs in the same workflow in series (using `needs`), enabling them to be run separately according to a specific `if` condition when necessary?

Comment: @GuiFalourd I'm not sure it's always possible to merge the two workflows together if they have different triggers (e.g. PR closed for one and push to main branch for the other, meaning they'd both trigger when a PR is merged). Even assuming I could do that, doesn't `needs` require that the named job has already run in the workflow, rather than waiting for it to finish only if it is already running? i.e. if job B `needs` job A, and I trigger the workflow with some condition that would only activate job B, can it still run?

Comment: If you use an if condition at the job level, I believe it would work. What are currently the conditions for each job to run (is it push for one and PR for the other)?

Comment: @GuiFalourd Yes, that's the case - I have my main deploy workflow (runs on push to main), and a PR preview workflow (runs on PR opened/reopened/synchronize/closed) that both push to gh-pages. When a PR is closed, if it also a merged it creates a commit to the main branch, which triggers the deploy workflow. So the main deploy commit and the commit that removes the preview are the two that conflict

Answer (score 2):

I think the most modern approach is `concurrency` - using a proper key for it you can put as many workflows as you need into a queue.

Before concurrency, the best approach that was working for me was to detect problems on the GIT level.
You run all those workflows and let them push - there is nothing like `simultaneous` commits - one of them will be first the second one will be rejected.
I was implementing proper rejection handling - if git refuses to take a commit - you just retry it.
In case you need to regenerate your data taking into account `master` branch state - just `git reset`, `git pull` - try again - until it works.

Comment: Hmmm, that's interesting. You're right - when either workflow pushes, one of them should have failed at the Git level. I will have to look into why that didn't happen.